# Passing client's (browser) certificate to downstream proxy - is that possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, cors

**I got the following issue**: A browser send a CORS request to a server - this server requires client SSL/TLS authentication (so both, server and client should exchange their certificates). The server is on the different domain than the page loaded to the client - so it requires a CORS request.

**Issue 1**: IE11 abort preflight requests with two way SSL/TLS certification

**Resolution 1**: Make the request 'local' and setup an apache proxy (with RewriteRule - but it did't pass the client's certificate and then with proxy pass - but it didn't pass the client's certificate as well).

**Issue 2**: The client's certificate is not pass with rewrite rules and with proxy pass.

**The question**: Is there ANY way to pass the client's certificate with an apache proxy? (Without changing the server's API at all).

**PS**:
I've read many threads like this - [Apache SSL Proxy can't find client certificate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/412206/apache-ssl-proxy-cant-find-client-certificate?rq=1) but I didn't find any solution (and threads like this are old).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a server, that uses https with client certificates, then you can't put a normal application protocol-level proxy in front of it, the best you can do is a TCP plug or port redirect.

The application server isn't going to settle for a cert in an HTTP header when it wants evidence of ownership of a private key in TLS.  The TLS handshaking will need to occur between the client and the server.

Comment: actually I may be wrong about this.  It may be possible to configure a back end to do validation on a cert passed through by the reverse proxy after all.  e.g. see http://serverfault.com/questions/622855/nginx-proxy-to-back-end-with-ssl-client-certificate-authentication